# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for all the def function():

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a newbie. 
I am running python web application on AWS-Ubuntu.  My goal is to access this app from the browser with IP address.

I have configured Apache web server.  Below are my conf and wsgi file.

.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 13.58.200.92
ServerAdmin admin@13.58.200.92
WSGIDaemonProcess catalog threads=5
WSGIProcessGroup catalog
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/catalog/catalog.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/catalog/Catalog/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /static /var/www/catalog/Catalog/static
<Directory /var/www/catalog/Catalog/static/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

.wsgi file

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import sys
import os
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/catalog/")
sys.path.append('/var/www/catalog/Catalog')

from Catalog import Employee as application
application.secret_key = 'super'
```

catalog.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, 
jsonify
from flask import flash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, Department, Employee, User
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Anti Forgery State Token Code
from flask import session as login_session
import random
import string

# Import for 'Gconnect' step
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets, FlowExchangeError
import httplib2
import json
from flask import make_response
import requests

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

CLIENT_ID = json.loads(open('/var/www/catalog/Catalog/client_secrets.json',
                        'r').read())['web']['client_id']

app = Flask(__name__)

# Connect to Database and create database session
engine = create_engine('postgresql://empcat:empcat@localhost/emp_catalog')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

@app.route('/')
def showLogin():
    state = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase +
                string.digits) for x in range(32))
    login_session['state'] = state
    return render_template('login.html', STATE=state)


@app.route('/gconnect', methods=['POST'])
def gconnect():
    # Validate state token
    if request.args.get('state') != login_session['state']:
        response = make_response(json.dumps('Invalid state parameter.'), 
        401)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        return response
    # Obtain authorization code
```

Program is erroring out with below error

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[Mon May 07 01:07:49.166142 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30509:tid 
139706086553344] [remote 68.80.159.72:8163] mod_wsgi (pid=30509): Exception 
occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/catalog/catalog.wsgi'.
[Mon May 07 01:07:49.166236 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30509:tid 
139706086553344] [remote 68.80.159.72:8163] TypeError: 'module' object is 
not callable
```

at below code lines

def showLogin()

def gconnect and all other

I have tried commenting these lines.  But getting the same error at next def function line.

Comment: I am using python 3 and had installed libapache2-mod-wsgi.  Installing libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 solved the problem for me.